# Interprocess Communication between Excel & C# Application?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, ipc

I was wondering if there was a way to set up communication between an instance of excel and a C# Application. For instance, when a cell value changes, I would like to send the updated value to the C# Application in real time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need the Office [Primary Interop Assemblies,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which are a .Net wrapper for the COM API exposed by MS Office.  You can [consume events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms247300%28v=office.11%29.aspx) through these, so you might be able to set up a listener that will capture the event that you want.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what the example is doing. Would I be able to have an instance of Excel open and have it send cell updates to the C# Application using this? My initial idea was using sockets, but I was unable to determine how to keep a socket for sending data in Excel.

Comment: You can connect a remote process to Excel through the COM API.

Comment: I tried looking for some examples on setting this up, but couldn't find any. Do you know of any examples for setting up ipc using the COM API through excel?

Comment: I've done this before through .Net. Python and Visual BASIC. Excel isn't in-process if you use the automation API. COM is marshalling and unmarshalling the calls across a process boundary.  You can see the running instance of Excel in Process Explorer - in fact it will leak Excel processes if you don't shut them down properly. This [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084) describes how to do it with C#

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) project types available in Visual Studio to automate Office from C# code.  This ensures you use only managed code and do not rely on COM or the Primary Interop Assemblies being available/installed.

This is the preferred approach when compared to the COM solution.  For further information and examples, please take a look at the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430).

Comment: I don't think thats correct: to access Excel data VSTO uses PIA which uses COM