# Pass an Excel cell value to a C# Winforms Application

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I'd like to know what is the best way to pass an excel cell value to a C# application using VBA. So when I run a macro a value is sent to my C# app.

[Interprocess Communication between Excel & C# Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070531/interprocess-communication-between-excel-c-sharp-application)

Comment: Why not just write a VSTO add-in in C#?

Comment: I already have a C# app. Can a VSTO add-in send data to a standalone C# app?

Comment: What do you mean by "send data"? Does the C# app accept data through a named pipe? Command line parameters? There are a lot of ways to transfer data from one application to another...

Comment: An Excel user works with a data table which contains ID when an operation is successful the row is deleted and send to another sheet. I'd like to send the row ID  (example: 1450  )to my C# app to do some operation in a SQL database.

Comment: I understand that, but it doesn't say *how you intend to receive it* on the C# application's side. Really seems like something that should be inside a VSTO without the external application otherwise your app has to be running at the same time as Excel for this to work.

Comment: Yes, the app runs as service in the background and has a GUI when the user opens the app.